# Pass different combinations of arguments in argparse

Tags: python, shell

## Problem

I am trying to run some code written in Python. The behavior of the code depends on three parameters (let's call them `param1`, `param2`, and `param3`) now.

Since each of these parameters could take multiple values. Running all combinations (more than 70) seems to be an impossible task. I saw people using shell script to automate this process. However, the following shell I wrote does not work (I am not familiar to shell).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for param1 in "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
do
    for param2 in "independent" "dependent"
    do
        for param3 in 0 1 2 3 4 5
        do
            python exp.py --param1 $(param1) --param2 $(param2) --param3 $(param3)
        done
    done
done
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong parentheses, use `{` and `}`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for param1 in "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
do
    for param2 in "independent" "dependent"
    do
        for param3 in 0 1 2 3 4 5
        do
            python exp.py --param1 ${param1} --param2 ${param2} --param3 ${param3}
        done
    done
done
```